# Empty DataFrame's rows do not have `name`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, apply

If I create a non-empty empty DataFrame, then I can access the index while using `apply` by accessing the `name` field.

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.__version__  # '1.2.4'

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [5,2,1]}, index=[1,2,3])
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.name, axis=1))

1    1
2    2
3    3
dtype: int64
```

However, this does not seem to be the case for an empty DataFrame.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3])
print(df.apply(lambda x: x.name, axis=1))

1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Why is this the case and what can be done to achieve the non-empty behaviour?

#### Further context

In my case, I am actually interested in a behaviour similar to this:

```py
def f(n):
    return [n, n+1]

df.apply(lambda x: f(x.name), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

I would like to be able to `join` the result to the DataFrame afterwards.

Comment: Look at your code twice, in the second one, you are not using `name` attribute

Comment: You want to create a DataFrame with no actual data beyond the indices, but use the indices for something meaningful? Why not just use a Series?

Comment: @Don'tAccept thanks, you're right, I made a typo in the post. I corrected it, the problem is still the same.

Comment: @Dahn, your question will be reopened if that is the case

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I'm writing a function that accepts a dataframe and fails for this reason (if the dataframe only has the index). I don't see a reason why it should behave differently in that case.

Comment: Well, if you just want something that gets the index from your input DataFrame and works in the general case... while I appreciate your commitment to "special cases aren't special enough to break the rules", is the "simple is better than complex" approach of `df.index` somehow insufficient?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have added some context to perhaps help direct the answers. I suppose you'd suggest using `pd.DataFrame({n: f(n) for n in df.index})` in this case?

Comment: That's one possible workaround, sure. Afraid I can't really tell you any more. Your existing approach does seem like it should work.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sure, thanks for your comments! This just seemed like an API inconsistency that I thought I'd ask about.